# Insert an entire row into an InnoDB table from another if the ID doesn't exsist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to insert data from one table to another, only if the entire row doesn't exsist.

Each row has an auto-incrementing ID. I was just going to check aganist the ID and insert the row if not.

I've seen people use:

- `INSERT IGNORE` - Which I haven't seen a clear explanation on.
- `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` - Which isn't ideal as I don't want to update any exsisting rows, I want to insert new ones.

The code I've written so far doesn't seem to be working:

```
INSERT INTO $tableNameOrig o
SELECT * FROM $tableNameTemp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM $tableNameOrig WHERE o.id=t.id);
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks for your time, I've been racking my brain for hours!

**UPDATE - Solved**

It turns out by not assigning each table name a letter (o and t) and using the table names throughout the query it works:

```
INSERT INTO $tableNameOrig
SELECT * FROM $tableNameTemp
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM $tableNameOrig WHERE $tableNameOrig.id = $tableNameTemp.id);
```

That's a weight of my shoulders!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO $tableNameOrig
SELECT * FROM $tableNameTemp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM $tableNameOrig WHERE $tableNameOrig.id = t.id);
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO $tableNameOrig
SELECT * FROM $tableNameTemp t
WHERE t.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM $tableNameOrig);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, I worked it out myself by replacing the 'o' and 't' with their respectvie table names throughout the query!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
(
    'SpongeBob','Squarepants','0415252522'
)";

// Execute query
if(mysql_query($sql,$con))
    echo "data inserted";
else
    echo "could not insert data";
////dis will allow to do it
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse, but I don't see how this answers my question, I'm afraid.

Comment: is this answer have any relation to the question?